# Maintaining different apps sharing the same code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I have a Rails app that is deployed on one site. I want to now be able to create, maintain and deploy a copy of this app but with slightly different configurations and a different frontend.

The main differences would be in the html and css but there are also some differences in the text used across the site (maybe I need to use i18n).

I have thought about using git submodules for each of the different view folders. While this would allow me to keep the commits for these views separate, it's not clear how I could then specify which view folder to use. This doesn't feel like a good solution.

Ideally, I would like to be able to keep these apps in separate repositories but also be able to share code between them.

What would be the best approach for maintaining multiple apps?

Comment: You can use different branches in the repository for the different sites.

Comment: One of the ways would be to factor out the duplicated code into gems/engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you could potentially do this:

---

[**Templates**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html)

> Application templates are simple Ruby files containing DSL for adding
>   gems/initializers etc. to your freshly created Rails project or an
>   existing Rails project.

Never used them myself, but apparently, templates help you give some structure to new Rails application. Although they're meant to give you standardized Gem files etc, I've seen people doing some pretty intricate things with templates

---

[**Engines**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html)

You may also be able to use Engines to help:

> Engines can be considered miniature applications that provide
>   functionality to their host applications. A Rails application is
>   actually just a "supercharged" engine, with the Rails::Application
>   class inheriting a lot of its behavior from Rails::Engine

Although these seems to be deep application-level technology, you may be able to benefit from using them for specific functionality inside your applications

---

**DB?**

If you're only changing the front-end, why don't you just focus on using the same DB for both Rails apps? This will give you the ability to customize the frontend as required, thus helping you do what you want, instead of constraining yourself

I'd be able to give more definite recommendations if you detail exactly which parts you want to change & why!

Comment: I went with Rails Engines in the end. Thanks.